# Insert space if uppercase letter is preceded and followed by one lowercase letter - Python

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp

Is there a way to insert aspace if it contains a uppercase letter (but not the first letter)?

For example, given **"RegularExpression"** I´d like to obtain **"Regular Expression"**.

I tried the following regex:

```
re.sub("[a-z]{1}[A-Z][a-z]{1}", " ","regularExpression")
```

Unfortunately, this deletes the matching pattern:

```
regula pression
```

I would prefer a regex solution, yet would be thankful for any working solution.
Thanks!

Comment: What about "USA"?

Comment: should not be split, just if Uppercase letter is within a string, and followed/preceded by a lowercase letter, respectively.

Comment: If you merely wish to insert a space at various locations in the string you should not use the term "split". Splitting a string means returning an array or list containing different parts of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following:

```
import re

s = "RegularExpression"
re.sub(r"([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)", r"\1 \2", s)
```

which means "put a space between the first match group and the second match group", where the match groups are a cap followed by one or more non-caps.

Comment: Thanks mate, that´s exactly what I was craving for. Just a note, I´d slightly edited it to: "([a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)"

Comment: Cheers, bud. If it helped, feel free to check it as an answer to signify it helped you arrive there.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: s = 'RegularExpression'

In [2]: answer = []

In [3]: breaks = [i for i,char in enumerate(s) if char.isupper()]

In [4]: breaks = breaks[1:]

In [5]: answer.append(s[:breaks[0]])

In [6]: for start,end in zip(breaks, breaks[1:]):
   ...:     answer.append(s[start:end])
   ...:

In [7]: answer.append(s[breaks[-1]:])

In [8]: answer
Out[8]: ['Regular', 'Expression']

In [9]: print(' '.join(answer))
Regular Expression
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Lookbehind `"(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])"`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "RegularExpression"
print(re.sub(r"(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", r" \1", s))
```

**Output:**

```
Regular Expression
```

Comment: You might also use the full match instead of a group `print(re.sub(r"(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]", r" \g<0>", s))` ++

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, when an uppercase letter is preceded by a lowercase letter you wish to insert a space between them. You can do that by using `re.sub` to replace (zero-width) matches of the following regular expression with a space.

```
r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kOHM17/1/) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python code](http://tpcg.io/8GNCYh2I)

Note that the SUBSTITUTION box at the regex demo link contains one space.

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=[a-z])  : use a positive lookbehind to assert that the match is preceded
              by a lowercase letter
(?=[A-Z])   : use a positive lookahead to assert that the match is followed
              by an uppercase letter
```

For the string `'RegularExpression'` the regex matches the location between the letters `'r'` and `'E'` (i.e., a zero-width match).

Comment: @Thefourthbird, my replacement for your em-dash (`—`).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, one way using `re.findall`:

```
re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]+", "RegularExpression")
```

Output:

```
['Regular', 'Expression']
```