# Attempt to split word if uppercase (without enumerate, function or regex) leads to errors (e.g. not enough value to unpack)

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python. In this context I need to split a word when encountering an upper case, convert it as a lower case and then insert a "_".

I have seen various quite complex answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63715861/insert-space-if-uppercase-letter-is-preceded-and-followed-by-one-lowercase-lette), but I am trying to do it as simply as possible.

So far, here is my code:

```
word = input("What is the camelCase?")

for i , k in word:
    if i.isupper() and k.islower():
        word2 = k + "_" + i.lower + k
        print(word2)
    else:
        print(word)
```

This leads to "`not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`" after I input my word.

Another attempt here:

```
word = input("What is the camelCase?")

for i and k in word:
    if i.isupper() and k.islower():
        word2 = k + "_" + i.lower + k
        print(word2)
    else:
        print(word)
```

In this case I cannot even write my word, I directly have the error: "`cannot assign to expression`"

A proposed option has been as follows:

```
word = input("What is the camelCase?")

word2 = ""

for i, char in enumerate(word):
    if i > 0 and char.isupper() and word[i - 1].islower():
        word2 += "_" + char.lower()
    else:
        word2 += char

print(word2)
```

However, I also do not want to use "enumerate".

I think that I have something almost ok now, which is this:

```
word = input("What is the camelCase? ")


for char in word:
    if char.islower():
        print(char)

    else:
        print("_" + char.lower())
```

Sadly the output that it gives me is not perfect, for "testTest" I have:

```
t
e
s
t
_t
e
s
t
```

Comment: This is completely absurd.  `enumerate()` is *exactly* what you need here, in order to access the adjacent character in the string.  If you're going to refuse to use basic Python functionality, you might as well refuse to use Python at all.

Comment: Ok. Many thanks. I just feel that there "must" be another way. Because this only comes later in my course. And so I feel that I "must" use something else, otherwise this would have been introduced at the same time? A bit like in some cases rather than using a library to make things easier, in order to go a bit deeper, there is a need to do the thing from scratch?

Comment: Have you learned `zip` and string slicing?

Comment: If you mean by string slicing something like "print(b[2:5])" then yes. For "zip" no. But I think I may have a way now! Without anything!

Comment: I mean using loop and only loop and isupper()

Comment: I feel that with this new proposal, I am almost there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to get the string "test_test" from the input "testTest", then the problem lies in the `print()`. `print()` automatically ends in a new line. To change this, you can add the `end` parameter. In your case:

```
for char in word:
    if char.islower():
        print(char, end="")

    else:
        print("_" + char.lower(), end="")
```

`end=""` has been added to each print function, so it will now end it with no new line. In other cases, you could use it to end in a space, etc. See [this helpful article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gfact-50-python-end-parameter-in-print/) for more information. This will make it so that your output is in one line, and will read, `test_test`.

This is how you can fix the code you already have.

Comment: Yes it works!!! Many thanks!!! I am stupid for not having been aware that "end" would solve this. I understand why people strongly downvoted the question, even it pained me to see this...